# Changeset detecting change on NumberType erroneously

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Symfony 3.2 form that uses a NumberType. I use this field for a price that has no decimals (cars, real estate, i.e. prices we don't use cents for).

I also have a preUpdate listener that detects changes to the Entity to write an audit log. Whenever submitting the form, the price such as 28000 in the form field will show up as 28000.0 and therefore will show a difference, appearing in my changeset.

I cannot figure out how to get rid of this. I have the "scale" parameter set on both the form type and the Entity itself to 0, which I thought would eliminate any decimal, but it doesn't.

I originally was just using a TextType but that had its own issue by treating it as a text field so it would compare 28000 to "28000" and also treat that as a change when it really didn't.

Any ideas?

Vardump of changeset in listener:

```
"salePrice" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 32888
    1 => 32888.0
]
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Groups({"feed"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="sale_price", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $salePrice;
```

FormType:

```
->add('salePrice', NumberType::class, [
    'label' => 'Sale: $',
    'required' => false,
    'scale' => 0,
    'attr' => ['class' => 'size-sm input-sm'],
])
```

Comment: This link can help you : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5594

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [IntegerType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/integer.html) instead:

```
->add('salePrice', IntegerType::class, [
    'label' => 'Sale: $',
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => ['class' => 'size-sm input-sm']
])
```

Can you try that and see if it works better. The NumberType is for non-integers.